# Can't get Bootstrap Tooltips and Modal to work together

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-modal, popper.js

I'm hoping someone might be able to help me with this issue that I've been struggling with for hours.  I’m developing a .NET Core application using Visual Studio.  I’m trying to use the Bootstrap Tool Tips which leverages Popper.  When I get the Tooltips to work, I can’t load Modals, when I get Modals to work, I can’t get Tooltips to work.

Tooltips works when I install Bootstrap (4.6.0) via Nuget.  When I try to load a modal, I get the following error:

> TypeError: $('#journalEntryModal').modal is not a function. (In
> '$('#journalEntryModal').modal('show')',
> '$('#journalEntryModal').modal' is undefined)

In order for the Modal functionality to work, I have to do the following:

1. Remove the Bootstrap as a Nuget Package
2. Manually download Bootstrap 4.6.0 and include it in my solution
3. Download Popper.js 2.9.0 and include it in my solution

When that happens and I hover over an element that has a tooltip, I get the following error:

> TypeError: Object is not a constructor (evaluating 'new
> Popper__default['default'](this.element, tip,
> this._getPopperConfig(attachment))')

Note that I'm using JQuery 3.5.1.  When I use Bootstrap via the Nuget install, I don't include the BOOTSTRAP & POPPER section.

```
@* ==============      JQUERY    ================== *@
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/lib/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/lib/jqueryui/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/lib/jquery.inputmask/jquery.inputmask.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/lib/jquery.inputmask/bindings/inputmask.binding.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/lib/jquery-validate/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/lib/jquery-toast-plugin/jquery.toast.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/lib/jquery-tokeninput/js/jquery.tokeninput.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/lib/bootstrap-chosen/chosen.jquery.js"></script>

    @* ==============      BOOTSTRAP & POPPER    ================== *@
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/lib/popper.js/umd/popper.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/lib/bootstrap-4.6.0/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

Any ideas on what I could be doing wrong?

Thanks a bunch.

--- Val

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally got this working by importing version 1.14.7 of popper from the following:

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js